# Can't insert NULL into one of PK Fields in a table with a double PK

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a table with the following architecture:

```
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.createTable('employeesOrders', {
        employeeId: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(12),
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        orderType: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: true,    /// **Notice NULLs are allowed!!!**
            defaultValue: null,       
        },
        .............
        ..............
        ................ 
        // More irrelevant fields
    }, {
        indexes: [
            {
                fields: ['employeeId',orderType],
                unique: true,
            },
        ],
    }),
    down: queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable('employeesOrders'),
};
```

When I try to migrate data into this table , such as:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "employeeId": "ASAFDSFD",
      "orderType": 3000      
    },
    {
      "employeeId": "1243FDFF"
    }
  ]
}
```

Sequelize throws an exception:

```
ERROR: null value in column "orderType" of relation "employeesOrders" violates not-null constraint
child_process.js:655
    throw err;
    ^
```

How can we allow to have a double PK of `<employeeId,orderType>` and allow `orderType` to be NULL ?

**EDIT:**

```
 up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.createTable('employeesOrders', {
         runId: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        employeeId: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(12),
            allowNull: false,       
        },
        orderType: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
        }
    },{
        indexes: [
            {
                fields: ['employeeId',orderType],
                unique: true,
            },
        ],
    });
```

When putting new data into the **EDITED VERSION** then this data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "employeeId": "ASAFDSFD",
      "orderType": 3000      
    },
   {
      "employeeId": "ASAFDSFD",
      "orderType": 3000      
    },
  ]
}
```

Is inserted into the DB , even though it's supposed to be unique.

Comment: You can't have `null` values in primary key, but you can have unique index with null values ([https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pDN7p5ZKbQsjbWEu4cM1aC/0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pDN7p5ZKbQsjbWEu4cM1aC/0)).

Comment: @Philippe: I need to have a `NULL` value in `orderType` , what would be the best choice ?

Comment: Like i said you can't have nulle values in primary key, but you can have null values in unique index. So create unique index instead of primary key...

Comment: @Philippe: OK , but how does a unique index helps resolve this issue ? If we can't insert NULLs then it seems useless.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Comment: @JAN it is the primary key that has put an implicit not null constraint on the column removing the primary key should allow you to insert null values.

Comment: @JAN : If the primary key have to be set on the 2 columns then add default value on `order_type`. Else remove primary key to insert your datas

Comment: @Philippe: Can you please see the edited question ? I've used a *Unique Key* with RunId , but it allows me to insert the same data twice....